# multiple match in regex

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds

The pattern and text are shown online https://regex101.com/r/aL5dD4/2
The pattern should find node values of span elements that are located between code tags.

Text is as follows:

```
<code>
    <div>
        <span ds = 'dsds'>12 3 ->;:4</span><span>abc</span>
    </div>
</code>
```

Regex pattern is as follows:

```
/(?<=<code>).*?<span[^>]*?>(.*?)(?=<\/span>.*?<\/code)/gs
```

I need it to match both node values `12 3 ->;:4` and `abc`.

But only the first is found.

How to get this?
Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1848654

Comment: Keep it simple, don't use lookaround, use groups: [`<code>.*?<span[^>]*?>(.*?)</span><span>(.*?)</span>`](https://regex101.com/r/xT8tH5/1)

Answer (score 0):

Regex is never a good tool to parse out HTML/XML. Use `DOM` as below:

```
$html=<<<EOF
<code>
    <div>
        <span ds = 'dsds'>12 3 ->;:4</span><span>abc</span>
    </div>
</code>
EOF;

$xpath = new DOMXPath(@DOMDocument::loadHTML($html));    
$nodeList = $xpath->query('//code/div/span');

$vals = array();
for($i=0; $i < $nodeList->length; $i++) {
    $vals[] = $nodeList->item($i)->nodeValue;
}

print_r( $vals );
```

[**Code Demo**](http://ideone.com/E6tKMZ)

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12 3 ->;:4
    [1] => abc
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I agree with the sentiment against using Regex for HTML, to answer your question, eliminating the look behind `(?<=<code>)` allows the Regex to find the second occurrence as well. This leaves the following regex:

```
<span[^>]*?>(.*?)(?=<\/span>.*?<\/code)
```

**NOTE**:This returns two separate matches and does not require the string to be found in a  element. To require that a match be in a code block, you could use @HamZa's commented solution (though this solution provides 1 match with two groups as the strings), which may even be closer to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do is first grab the code block with something like `/<code[^>]*?>(.*?)<\/code>/gs` and on these matches `/<span[^>]*?>(.*?)<\/span>/gs`.

These 'simpler' regexes also make it easier to debug, should you run into problems. Also it this approach extracts all spans from multiple code blocks sequentially.